# How does Windows choose a resolution when duplicating displays?

Tags: windows, display, resolution, projector

An example: I have a Windows 7 desktop connected to a monitor with a native resolution of 1600x900 and support for several lower resolutions.  I also connect a projector with a native resolution of 1024x768 and support for several higher resolutions (up to 1920x1200).  I use the Windows + P key and select "Duplicate".  This causes both the monitor and the projector to change to the same resolution, usually 1024x768, but sometimes 1600x900.  Either displays a picture, but with different scaling/cropping.

I've confirmed that EDID is working because if I select "Computer only" or "Projector only" it uses the native resolution of each one automatically.  I've also checked in Display Settings that the monitor is always display 1 and the projector is display 2.

How does Windows choose what resolution to use?  How can I change this behavior *before* duplicate is selected?

Comment: If you choose "duplicate", then they will be set to the same resolution, which will be the highest that is seen as supported on both displays.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 In my example, that would be 1600x900, but it's not what happens in my experience.